# Renaming a Hard Drive

Tags: terminal, hard-disk

I have a secondary internal HDD to store auxiliary data. I want to give it a better name. How do I do it?

Comment: I assume you want to change the label of the file system. If it's an ext file system you can use `e2label <device> label` or `gparted` if you want a GUI.

Comment: I'd prefer to just do it with the command line. It's a FAT32 filesystem.

Comment: Use `dosfslabel <device> label`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For FAT16 and FAT32 partitions, use `mlabel` from the `mtools` package or `dosfslabel`

**Method 1# using `dosfslabel`** ( As @Macro suggested )

Umount Partition

```
sudo umount <device>
```

Set Label using :

```
sudo dosfslabel <device> label
```

**Method 2# using `mtools`**

Install package using

```
sudo apt-get install mtools
```

unmount the external drive, Partitions generally need to be unmounted before you can fiddle with them, so unmount the partition of the device you want to change the label for:

```
sudo umount <device>
```

where device name can be `/dev/sdbx`, you can find in `sudo fdisk -l`

Check the current label

```
sudo mlabel -i <device> -s ::
```

Note that we're using the special "::" drive which allows us to specify the device descriptor on the command line; otherwise we'd have to edit ~/.mtoolsrc to assign a drive letter.

Change the label

```
sudo mlabel -i <device> ::<label>
```

[Reference Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive)